# How to create csv file for each line in a text file?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file `price.txt` that contains the following rows:

```
open 
high 
low 
close
```

I need to create a separate csv files for each row in the text file and name the csv files as `price1.csv`, `price2.csv` and so on

I tried the following code

```py
with open('price.txt') as infile, open('outfile.csv','w') as outfile: 
    for line in infile: 
        outfile.write(line.replace(' ',','))
```

I am getting only one csv file that has the following rows

```
open
high
low
close
```

How can I create a csv file for each row?

Answer (score 0):

Here the code to obtain a different file called `price1.csv`, `price2.csv` etc for every line (with the substitution whitespace - comma that you put in your example) with comments:

```py
### start a counter for the filename number
i = 0
with open('price.txt') as infile:
    ### open a loop over rows of input file
    for line in infile :
        ### add 1 to counter
        i += 1
        ### create the output filename for the row
        newfile_name = "price" + str(i) + ".csv"
        ### write in the new filename the modified row
        with open(newfile_name,'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(line.replace(' ',','))
```